# How to create a custom Tag Helper for razor performed also in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I created a custom Tag Helper in C# to perform some check on some line of code(for example to check if a key is present in it), I'll insert an example to explain it

```
<mycheck key="test">
<div>... some html code</div>
</mycheck>
```

I would like to use this also in javascript code, but I see that this is not interpreted when wrote in javascript code, for example in a case like this:

```
<script>
    <mycheck key="test">
    ... some javascript code
    </mycheck>
</script>
```

How can I use my tag helper also in javascript code? Otherwise, is there some different solution?

Comment: A tag helper is executed on the server and is written in C#. So how would you think that could be technically feasible? Instead you could write the same in JavaScript or expose a Web API function to be called from JavaScript

Comment: @DanielSchmid I know this, in fact I want to execute my tag helper on the server obviously, and if the javascript code contains my key, then I want to do some operation on the code inside the tag

Comment: Two strategies come in my mind. Traditionally you would expose a function through web API. You would then call this function from javascript code. Alternatively you could implement a Blazor server side component. This way you would not need to write any JavaScript.

Comment: see [TagHelperComponents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/th-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1), it allowes to add scripts to the html

Answer (score 0):

The tag helper only exists server-side. It will be rewritten into some other HTML tag when the response is sent to the client. You cannot use it within a JS template, because it can only be processed server-side, but is only present, then, client-side, after the server is already done.

If you need to be able to render components client-side, then you should use a client-side library like Angular, React, Vue, etc. and create components with those.